# A few object of Qt Designer Form Class. Is few object = few dialog window?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qt-designer

I have a designer form class of some vehicles where constructor holds a index of vehicle:

```
Vehicle::Vehicle(QWidget *parent, int _index) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Vehicle)
{
  this->_index = _index;
}
```

In main class, I create an object of class:

```
Vehicle* vehicle = NULL;
```

and I have a 10 buttons to open a 10 different dialog class of Vehicles:

```
void MainWindow::OnOpenDialog1()
{
  if(vehicle==NULL)
    vehicle = new vehicle(this, 0);

  if(vehicle->isHidden()) {
    vehicle->show();
  }
  else
    vehicle->hide();
}

void MainWindow::OnOpenDialog2()
{
  if(vehicle==NULL)
    vehicle = new vehicle(this, 1);

  if(vehicle->isHidden()) {
    vehicle->show();
  }
  else
    vehicle->hide();
}
.....
```

but in this way I open only one dialog, and other buttons opened the same dialog.

Shuld I create a 10 object of class?

```
Vehicle* vehicle1 = NULL;
Vehicle* vehicle2 = NULL;
Vehicle* vehicle3 = NULL;
....
```

I thought I could use a single object class and insert only index in the constructor and the data displayed on one changing form depends on index?

Comment: can you show a code that manipulates the vehicle depends on the index?

Comment: Do you need all you dialogs to be non modal? Would you like to be able to show several of them at once?

Comment: Now it doesn't work because in OnOpenDialog2 vehicle is not NULL, this is why you get never constructed dialogs with other indexes